# Setting PowerPoint font color with Apple Script

Tags: applescript, powerpoint

I'm trying to use Apple script to set the font color of all selected PowerPoint shapes.  I used something similar to this to set fill and line color, but I haven't been able to get it to work for font color.

```
tell application "Microsoft PowerPoint"
set theShapeRange to shape range of selection of active window
set n to (count shapes of theShapeRange)
repeat with i from 1 to n
    tell shape i of theShapeRange
        set font color of text range of it to {99, 99, 99}
    end tell
end repeat
```

end tell

Comment: The '2004' docs advise the following: `set font color of font of text range of text frame of sldTitle to ({0, 0, 255} as RGB color)`

Comment: That's just what I needed, thank you @Mockman

Comment: Glad it worked. You should throw it into an answer and mark it as accepted. Then it would be easier for others to find. Regards.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on the guidance provided by Mockman in a comment above, this seems to work.

```
tell application "Microsoft PowerPoint"
    set theShapeRange to shape range of selection of active window
    set n to (count shapes of theShapeRange)
    repeat with i from 1 to n
        tell shape i of theShapeRange
            set font color of font of text range of text frame of it to {99, 99, 99}
        end tell
    end repeat
end tell
```